# ionic-material demo on android bowser/hybrid-App templates not showing

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-material

I successfully build the ionic-material demo
[Ionic-material Demo](https://github.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/tree/master/demo)

when I do ionic server
the browser opens and the app works as excpected but
when compiled on android

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
ionic run android
```

the app compiled and run but I'm not able to show diffrent screens on navigate the url changes and the floting action buttons show up but not te template files ?
what I'm doing wrong or what might be the problem ??
I added  `alert("debug")` in the controller and the alert is showing up on navigation so just the template not rendering

note ionic is built over AngulaJs so Angular experts can help too

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Steps i'd take to debug this are:

1. run `ionic serve`, and check the console for angularJS errors and resolve any if there are any
2. run - `ionic platform add android` + `ionic run android` with a connected android device and from another console window run the following command to run logcat via ADB

   `adb logcat CordovaActivity:V CordovaWebView:V CordovaWebViewClient:V IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient:V CordovaLog:V *:S`
3. Resolve any errors the ADB flags
4. Try `ionic platform add android` + `ionic run android` again

Note: ionic handles touch events in browser and on device so this will not be the issue, it is likely it is a syntax error that has stopped the compile to device

Comment: i open the URLon my android device native browser and i got the same behavior  the only thing touch do is showing the ripple effect  so it is not android issue any clue ??

Comment: the `ionic-serve` command is supposed to be ran from the browser of the machine you are developing on, usually `localhost:8100` and is for debugging purposes - it will not deploy your app to your phone

Comment: no I'm not . I used 
ionic serve --address 192.168.1.133
which allow browsers on ios and other PCs on the same network to run the app
i'm only facing this problem on android browsers and when I compiled it to APK

Comment: Are you getting any errors showing in ADB Logcat after deploying and running the application?

Comment: yes found the errors <br />
TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'remove'
    at Scope.$scope.clearFabs (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:85:21)
    at new <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:120:20) <br />
Iremoved this line andd it works
$scope.$parent.clearFabs()